# How to check whether selectbox contains any option with specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

In jQuery, how can I check that a selectbox contains a specific class or not? For example, in the below code snippet, I want to check whether the selectbox with id "customerIds" contains any option with class "C" or "D".

```
<select id="customerIds" onchange="doOperation()">
    <option value="default"> Start..</option>
    <option value="1" class="A"> 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="B"> 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="C"> 3 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hasClass()` method: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

For example:

```
$("#customerIds").find("option").hasClass("A");
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance you can use `:has`.

```
var hasOption = !!$("#customerIds:has(option.C,option.D)").length;
```

Or `.children()` as well, which may prove to be faster.

```
var hasOption = !!$("#customerIds").children("option.C,option.D").length;
```

```
var hasOption = !!$("#customerIds > option.C,option.D").length;
```

Comment: You don't really need `:has()` here. The regular descendant selector works just fine.

Comment: Yup, I was adding more alternatives afterwards. The advantage of using `:has` can't be seen here though

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if($("#customerIds option[class='C']").length > 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
if ($('#customerIds > .C').length > 0 || $('#customerIds > .D').length > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

OR a more flexible/optimizable one

```
var selectBox = $('#customerIds');

if (selectBox.find('.C').length > 0 || selectBox.find('.D').length > 0) {
    // ...
}
```